# Populating Dropdown using PHP Query

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to populate dropdown-list with new data by calling a PHP page which returns an array of values.

Here is my PHP page:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['catid']))
{
    $conn =     mysql_connect("localhost","krupa4e_skyways","skyways@1347","krupa4e_skyways");

            if (!$conn)
             {
                echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
                exit;
            }


            if (!mysql_select_db("krupa4e_skyways")) 
            {
                echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
                exit;
            }

                     $cat=$_GET['catid'];


            $getsubcategoriesssql='select scid,sc_name from subcategories where catid='.$cat;
                            $result=mysql_Query($getsubcategoriesssql,$conn);

                            if (!$result) 
                            {
                                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                            }


                    $output=array();

                            while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
                            {
                            array_push($output,$row[0],$row[1]);

                            }


echo $output;


}
?>
```

How can I obtain the data I need using jQuery and bind that to an array, and later to a dropdown-list?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json_encode` to print that array in PHP code as a JSON string, and in javascript you can easily parse that JSON to an object.